# Nested comments in WordPress theme

Tags: theme-development, comments

I'm creating own theme to WordPress. Got problem with nested comments. I have enabled option in admin panel for two levels. And what next? I've read a lot of net articles but nothing helpful. I want to create own comments template. comment_reply_link() function not working, I'm stupid as sh*t in it. How I can do it with no pasting written code from net into function.php. And how get level of comment? Please about help.

Comment: You need to add and activate the comment reply script.

Comment: Add this code at the top of your theme's header.php file, before closing the head tag // For threaded comments if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments')) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

Comment: I know what lets me to be about doing it - my own template I must put into comment list function as callback.

Comment: We need to see your comments template (i.e. `comments.php`) markup, in order to be able to help.

Comment: @Sudar Got the link to the original answer, you've taken this snippet from? Then we could mark this as "exact duplicate". Thanks.